# Using Getch_() values and movement inside of an array

Tags: c++

I'm working on a small rpg game in my spare time and to improve my skill as a c++ coder. Because i wanted to do it without outside libraries(next is sfml), i'm drawing the board using for loops and cout statements.

The problem i'm having is actually with how i move around the pseudo-board. I use Getch_() values in order to use case statements and move the 'X' around the board. (X being the player). Right now, i can use all of the movement features except for the 'down' case. All of the statements are the exact same except i can't use the 'down' feature. i.e.

```
    case KEY_UP:
        Beep(2000, 200);
        system("CLS");
        for (int i = 0;i < 20;i++) {
            for (int j = 0;j < 20;j++) {
                if (i==CharacterY&&j==CharacterX) {
                    cout << "It's working!\n";
                    CharacterY = i - 1;
                    CharacterX = j;
                    if (StillEnemies == true) {
                        if (CharacterX == EnemyX&&CharacterY == EnemyY) {
                            cout << "A battle is started!\n\n";
                            Battle1();
                        }
                    }
                    if (CharacterX == NextX1&&CharacterY == NextY1) {
                        BoardChosen = 2;
                        //InitBoard2();
                    }
                    c = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        WhichBoard();
        cout << endl << "Up" << endl;//key up
        break;
```

and

```
    case KEY_DOWN:
        Beep(1000, 200);
        system("CLS");
        for (int i = 0;i < 20;i++) {
            for (int j = 0;j < 20;j++) {
                if (i == CharacterY&&j == CharacterX) {
                    cout << "It's working!\n";
                    CharacterY = i + 1;
                    CharacterX = j;
                    cout << CharacterX << " " <<CharacterY << endl;
                    if (StillEnemies == true) {
                        if (CharacterX == EnemyX&&CharacterY == EnemyY) {
                            cout << "A battle is started!\n\n";
                            Battle1();
                        }
                    }
                    if (CharacterX == NextX1&&CharacterY == NextY1) {
                        BoardChosen = 2;
                        //InitBoard2();
                    }
                    c = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        WhichBoard();
        cout << endl << "Down" << endl;   // key down
        break;
```

EDIT: lead in to the select/case statements

```
while (1)
{
    c = 0;

    switch ((c = _getch())) {
    case KEY_UP:
```

The second movement feature is the one causing the error. The line

```
CharacterY = i - 1;
```

Moves the character 'Up' one space in the array, with CharacterY obviously being up and down. Now it would make sense that

```
CharacterY = i + 1;
```

Should do the exact opposite and move the character down 1 space, right? well for whatever reason, it gets stuck in an infinite loop and the character falls off the bottom of the map because it continuously adds 1 until the 'X' can no longer fit into the array parameters and it's deleted.
I've tried putting this into a new file and running it, i've tried changing the case KEY_DOWN to a different key and both of those produce the same error.

My question is, what exactly is there error(if it's other than the one I previously identified) and how do I fix it? It's kind of hard to play the game if you can't move down. Also, tell me if i should include the entire project somewhere(it's three .cpp files and i'm unsure of how to put them all on here, this is my first post)

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "Getch_() values"?

Comment: i use the method Getch_() to get a key value from the ASCii table of values.while (1)
 {
  c = 0;

  switch ((c = _getch())) {
  case KEY_UP:

Comment: You mention `Getch_` in your title and `_getch` in your code (neither of which is standard). Can you update your question to show a complete self-contained program that exhibits the problem? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. And if you're doing something that depends on a particular environment, please say so in the question and add an appropriate tag. (Are you using MS Windows?)

Answer (score 1):

The way your code is written, it tests and potentially moves the character position in all 400 cycles through the loop.  In the case of moving down, you're increasing CharacterY by 1, so the next time through the outer loop, it will again detect it and move it.

The best thing you could do for yourself here is to isolate the logic that adjusts your character's position from the other logic.  Really, none of this logic requires the loops...

Comment: so i could do without the loops at all?

Comment: without the loops fixed it...idk why i thought they were needed, thank you!